# Having problems while JSON parsing in Java?

Tags: java, android, json

I have a `ListView` with 3 `TextView` that will display the Books title, author and published date from a book listing API.

Now the problem here is I can display the Books title and date but the authors element is in a `JSONArray`, for that I was thinking of running an inner for loop that would add the authors in the string variable but since the string variable is inside the inner loop it is not visible when I try to pass the variable to the Book custom class.

I can display the `String` within the “`volumeInfo`” `JSONObject`, it’s the “author” `JSONArray` that is giving me the problem.

Sorry for not explaining this clearly but any help would be appreciated.

Here is My JSON format

```
{  
"kind":"books#volumes",
"totalItems":1045,
"items":[  
  {  
     "kind":"books#volume",
     "id":"RVhsAQAAQBAJ",
     "etag":"6uHhm1spXck",
     "selfLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/RVhsAQAAQBAJ",
     "volumeInfo":{  
        "title":"Android Programming",
        "subtitle":"The Big Nerd Ranch Guide",
        "authors":[  
           "Bill Phillips",
           "Brian Hardy"
        ],
        "publisher":"Pearson Education",
        "publishedDate":"2013",
```

Here is my java code:

```
List<Book> bookLists = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(bookJSON);
        JSONArray bookArray = baseJsonResponse.getJSONArray("items");

        for (int i = 0; i <= bookArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject currentBook = bookArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject volumeInfo = currentBook.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");

            String bookTitle = volumeInfo.optString("title").toString();

            JSONArray authorArray = currentBook.getJSONArray("authors");

            for (int j =0; j <= authorArray.length(); j++) {

                String authorBook = authorArray.optString(0).toString(); // error
            }

            String publishedDate = volumeInfo.optString("publishedDate").toString();

            Book book = new Book(bookTitle, authorBook, publishedDate);
            bookLists.add(book);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e){

        Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the earthquake JSON results", e);
    }

    return bookLists;
```

Comment: `String authorBook; /*for-loop that assigns the value*/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to get the authors array from the currentBook JSON object where it doesn't exist. You need to get the authors array from the volumeInfo JSON object.

You then need to declare your string variable authorBook outside the scope of the for loop.

```
JSONArray authorArray = volumeInfo.getJSONArray("authors");
String authorBook = "";
for (int i = 0; i < authorArray.length(); i++) {
    // Add a comma after each author unless it is the last one.
    String author = authorArray.getString(i);
    if (i == authorArray.length() - 1) {
       authorBook = authorBook + author;
    } else {
       authorBook = authorBook + author + ", ";
    }
}
```

Your variable authorBook should be a string of the authors separated by a comma.

Comment: That's the problem, any variable declared or initialized within the inner loop is not visible outside it, if I declare the variable outside it I get a "variable not initialized" error within the inner for loop.

Comment: Edited answer to reflect initializing the authorBook variable correctly.

Comment: I am getting a JSON parsing error, when I completely comment out the inner for loop the authorBook populates as empty strings or any string hard-coded within the variable, authorBook is not getting parsed within the for loop or it's not visible outside it.

Comment: Initialize authorBook as an empty string before the for loop where you iterate through authorArray. If you comment out that loop, then authorBook will be the empty string you initialized it to. In the for loop in my example, you are just appending the individual authors to the empty string so it will look like "Author A, Author B, etc."

Comment: Yes I did initialized like you said but I am still getting a JSON parsing error, when I comment out the inner for loop and the author's JSON array the app works, authorBooks is not parsing correctly.

Keep in mind that Book Title and Published Date within the volumeInfo JSON object are populating correctly within the listview.

Comment: I apologize, I see what the issue is. You're parsing the authors from currentBook and not volumeInfo where it's nested. One sec let me edit answer.

Comment: I misread the JSON you posted, the snippet should work now when you update where you're initializing authorArray.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an to List to store the authors to the Book class
Then you parsing should look like that

`

```
JSONArray authorArray = currentBook.getJSONArray("authors");
List<String> authors = new ArrayList<>();

for (int j =0; j <= arr.length(); j++) {
    String author = authorArray.getString(i);
    authors.add(author);
}
// When you create the book 

 Book book = new Book(bookTitle, authorBook, publishedDate, authors);
 bookLists.add(book);
```

`

Comment: I have a custom class that takes 3 string variables and populates it on a custom listview, I tried populating the Arraylist within the inner loop like you said and then putting the strings from the arraylist in another variable after the loop and the strings in the custom class but I still got a parsing error.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray authorArray = currentBook.getJSONArray("authors");
List<String> authors = new ArrayList<>();

for (int j =0; j <= arr.length(); j++) {
    String author = authorArray.getString(j);
    authors.add(author);
}
// When you create the book 

 Book book = new Book(bookTitle, authorBook, publishedDate, authors);
 bookLists.add(book);


or use forech();
```

`